# highcharts - need to auto scroll on x-axis on every 5 seconds with hide scroll bar

Tags: highcharts

I want to create highcharts with auto scroll in axis and moving on every 5 seconds.
I also hide the x-axis scroll bar. It is hide by scrollbar enabled : false.

My fiddle is : http://jsfiddle.net/kj63cL1v/

```
xAxis: {
            type: 'category',
            max: 6,
            scrollbar: {
                enabled: true
            },
            tickLength: 0
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an interval after a chart is generated and call `setExtremes` method. Example:

```
    setInterval(() => {
        const xAxis = chart.xAxis[0];
        xAxis.setExtremes(xAxis.min + 1, xAxis.max + 1);
    }, 5000);
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5yha7xwv/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setExtremes

Comment: One point is that, after complete last data, it should be auto start from first point.

Comment: Hi @Kamal Sanghavi, Do you mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2t5hv8jc/ ?

Comment: Only 1 issue is there, if I change of jump from 1-1 step to 3 steps, it will not start to first point.
For ex. : xAxis.setExtremes(xAxis.min + 3, xAxis.max + 3);

Comment: This should resolve your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/f58Lyrkc/